# How to Index Multiple Columns, in a Space of a single column index in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

This is a question I came across during an interview.

Assume that you are given a database containing the columns: "**row_id**", "**payload_data**", and "**time_stamp**". But you can only keep index of one column at a time.

How to keep indexes for both "row_id" and "time_stamp"?

Comment: That does not make sense.  Perhaps the interviewer was less knowledgeable than you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question was supposed to be "smart" and the expected answer was:

> Make `row_id` the primary key of the table and create an index on `time_stamp`.

This way the table has only one additional index. The primary key is needed and created anyway.

All in all, the table has two indexes and, in my opinion, this is a low quality interview question.

Answer (score 2):

It's clearly an artificial requirement, because there's no reason to avoid multi-column indexes.

One solution is to create a virtual column that concatenates `row_id` with `time_stamp`, and index the virtual column.

```
CREATE TABLE `artificial` (
  `row_id` int NOT NULL,
  `time_stamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `payload_data` text,
  `row_id_time_stamp` varchar(20) 
      GENERATED ALWAYS AS (concat(`row_id`,':',`time_stamp`)) VIRTUAL,
  KEY `row_id_time_stamp` (`row_id_time_stamp`)
)
```

But that index isn't as flexible as a multi-column index. It can work if you are searching on both columns, but it won't work if you want to use `=` to search for a specific `row_id` value.

In other words, this condition can use the multi-column index but not the concat index:

```
... WHERE row_id = '1234'
```

To use the concat index, you'd either have to search for a pattern, or a concatenated value for both columns:

```
... WHERE row_id_time_stamp LIKE '1234:%'
... WHERE row_id_time_stamp = '1234:2017-10-12 22:27:00'
```

Another possible interpretation is that if `row_id` is the primary key, then a secondary index on `time_stamp` implicitly includes `row_id` because of the way InnoDB implements secondary indexes. So it might be a question testing MySQL/InnoDB internals.

Comment: While it is correct that the InnoDB includes the `PK` column in all indexes (as a hidden column), it is not possible to use such an index to search by values of the `PK` column.

Comment: Yes, you have to use the leftmost columns of any index. But if you had search terms for both time_stamp *and* row_id, it would still qualify as an index-only query.